# Using image created with CGBitmapContextCreate as an opengl texture

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, core-graphics

I'm generating an image using `quartz2d` and I want to use it as an `opengl` texture.
The tricky part is that I want to use as few bits per pixel as possible, so I'm creating `cgContext` as following:

```
int bitsPerComponent = 5;
int bytesPerPixel = 2;
int width = 1024;
int height = 1024;
void* imageData = malloc(width * height * bytesPerPixel);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGImageContext context = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, width * bytesPerPixel, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
//draw things into context, release memory, etc.
```

As stated in the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB), this is the only supported `RGB` pixel format for `CGBitmapContextCreate` which uses 16 bits per pixel.
So now I want to upload this imageData which looks like "1 bit skipped - 5 bits red - 5 bits green - 5 bits blue" into an opengl texture. So I should do something like this:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1, imageData);
```

That won't work because in this call I've specified pixel format as `5 red - 5 green - 5 blue - 1 alpha`. That is wrong, but it appears that there is no format that would match core graphics output.
There are some other options like `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_1_5_5_5_REV`, but those wont work on the `iphone`.

I need some way to use this `imageData` as a texture, but I really don't want to swap bytes around manually using memset or such, because that seems terribly inefficient.

Comment: Why the concern about 5 bits per pixel?  Why not just have your context be what works easiest for opengl and if your source images are different allow quartz to do the conversion when it draws it to your context?  I have all sorts of dynamic textures in my game and have never had these issues.

Comment: I've created this question back in 2010, when we were still supporting 2g deivces. 2g and 3g both had very little memmory, and the app was not a game - it was a ebook reader. We had to use at least 10MB of data just for our text parsing/styling/layout engine, and every tiny bit of bytes was vital. I'm not sure that someone might have to use this in 2012, but maybe there are still apps out there that get killed with memmory warning and want to reduce memmory footprint.

Comment: @Alexey: Can you please let us know, what is the resolution of image data that you are loading for texture?

Answer (score 2):

You do need to swap bits around to get it into a denser format like RGBA551 or RGB565, since as you note, CGBitmapContext does not support these formats for drawing (for simplicity and efficency's sake).

`memset` isn't going to do the trick, but there are "fast" conversion routines in `Accelerate.framework`.

See `vImageConvert_ARGB8888toRGB565(…)` and `vImageConvert_ARGB8888toARGB1555(…)`, available on iOS 5 and later.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 7.0, OS X.9 and later:

```
vImage_CGImageFormat fmt = {
    .bitsPerComponent = 5,
    .bitsPerPixel = 16,
    .colorSpace = NULL, // faster with CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage) if known to be RGB
    .bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little // ARGB1555 little endian
};
vImage_Buffer buf;
vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage( &buf, &fmt, NULL, cgImage, kvImageNoFlags );
```

...

```
free(buf.data);
```

Data is in buf.data, along with image height, width and rowBytes info. I don't recall what GL's requirements are for whether row padding is allowed. You can control that by preallocating the buf.data and buf.rowBytes fields and passing kvImageDoNotAllocate in the flags.

565_REV is kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little.
5551_REV is kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little